# Sound stop working - ALC892

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Some times my sound is muted, and I need reboot many times to back work.

But today, nothing happens/worked.

I try "everything" like Sound Troubleshooting, etc.

```
➜  ~  cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC892

➜  ~  lsmod | less
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 47562  0 
bnep                   18240  2 
bluetooth             212001  10 rfcomm,bnep
binfmt_misc            17541  1 
kvm                   422160  0 
ppdev                  17114  0 
sp5100_tco             13792  0 
joydev                 17694  1 
microcode              23030  0 
xpad                   18182  0 
ff_memless             13098  1 xpad
psmouse               102541  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
k10temp                13174  0 
edac_core              53053  0 
edac_mce_amd           23548  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32476  1 
parport_pc             32867  1 
asus_atk0110           18079  0 
i2c_piix4              13302  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    79855  1 
fglrx                5294799  140 
mac_hid                13254  0 
amd_iommu_v2           19228  1 fglrx
wmi                    19257  0 
snd_hda_intel          34063  5 
snd_hda_codec         135141  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97523  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    83674  19 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15092  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
hid_generic            12541  0 
usbhid                 47259  0 
hid                   100815  2 hid_generic,usbhid
pata_via               13702  0 
ahci                   25869  4 
pata_atiixp            13205  0 
libahci                27338  1 ahci
r8169                  62741  0
```

Comment: Did you, amongst "everything" also try to delete `~/.pulse`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the sound is muted whenever you have headphones or external speakers connected to computer. I had the problem that if I had headphones connected or speakers then the embedded speaker would not work. This problem is best known as "speakers will not mute"

Comment: Mute is not. I used some tutorials and working again. But this happens only in the login screen. When you load it to the desktop, since Ubuntu is selecting the incorrect output, for example, is to select the correct driver analog, but it selects the headphones. But sometimes the analog output does not work but the headphones (even though I only connecting speakers in it).